# How to iterate through database rows using max(ID) on button click event Sqlite - Python

Tags: python, database, sqlite, pyqt

The function below is connected to a button and when pressed sets the last row of the database(aka the last data entry) to the appropriate text boxes/lineEdits. What im trying to do is make it so each time the button is pressed it sets the next row(one before last) of the database to the text boxes/lineEdits. In short im trying to iterate through the database using forward and backward buttons. Is there somesort of next function?

```
def loadData(self):
    connection = sqlite3.connect('films.db')
    c = connection.cursor()
    cur = c.execute("SELECT * FROM FILMS WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM FILMS)")
    last_row = cur.fetchone() #returns the last row of the database(aka the max id) as a tuple
                              #tuple consists of 4 columns; ID,TITLE,YEAR,RATING


    title =last_row[1] #slicing the tuple to set the title into the text box
    self.edit_main_title.setText(title)
    self.edit_title.setText(title)

    year = last_row[2]
    self.edit_year.setText(year)

    ratings = last_row[3]
    self.edit_rating.setText(str(ratings))
```

I dont know if this could help but -1 from max id gives the row before the last

```
cur = c.execute("SELECT * FROM FILMS WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID)-1 FROM FILMS)")
```

Answer (score 1):

A different way of getting the largest ID is to use ORDER BY and LIMIT:

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM Films
ORDER BY ID DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Now if you have remembered that ID value, you can restrict the query to rows with a smaller ID value, so you get the largest value of the remaining rows:

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM Films
WHERE ID < ?
ORDER BY ID DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: could you expand on that please im relatively new to sqlite. where id is greater than what? what does desc mean? Thank you for replying , I really appreciate it

Comment: Less than the ID from the last step. [DESC documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby).

Comment: c.execute("SELECT * FROM FILMS WHERE ID < (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM FILMS) ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;").fetchone()   This gives me the same result as the one i had before.

Comment: You need to store the old ID in a variable in your program.